# Objective-C: send/recieve SOAP for Iphone with php webservice

Tags: php, objective-c, post, soap

i started programming with Objective-C some days ago, so im a beginner and also never made a webservice.
So i made a webservice with php with help of some tutorials. 
The php file looks like this:

```
<?php
function name($a){
$db = "app";
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "******");
mysql_select_db($db);
$zeile = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player Where Player_ID like $a"));
mysql_close();
return $zeile[1];           
}
$server=new SoapServer("profil.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("name");
$server->handle();

?>
```

And i also got a wsdl file.

When i test my webservice here : http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html 
i get  the following response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:profil" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-  ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP- ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:nameResponse>
<Result xsi:type="xsd:string">Test123</Result>
</ns1:nameResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The Result Test123 is exactly what i want to get inside my Objective-C program as a String, but i dont know how to do it. I already checked a lot of tutorials but i didnt get it. I just need to post 1 int value and get my string: "test123" back.

I hope someone can help me, that would be great.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you made your web service use SOAP. A RESTful service using JSON would have been more simple for a beginner.

Comment: thank you! i will try it with JSON now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no out of the box way to communicate with `SOAP` services in `iOS`. And actually it's not recommended. You can try the [wsdl2objc](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) library, but I don't recommend working with `SOAP` services. Make your service work with `JSON` and you will easily be able to serialize/deserialize it.

Comment: Thank you for that fast answer! 
Well i guess i will try it with JSON now.